# Diophantine question: find two positive numbers a and b such that $a\cdot b+a=c^3$ and $a\cdot b+b=d^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Diophantine question: find two positive numbers a and b such that $a\cdot b+a=c^3$ and $a\cdot b+b=d^3$

I solved this equation , the solution are rational; $\frac{112}{13}$ and $\frac{27}{169}$. Can this problem have more solutions?

Solution: We set parametric $a=t^3x$ and $b=x^2-1$.We have:

$a\cdot b=t^3x(x^2-1)=(tx)^3-t^3x$

Such that:

$a\cdot b+a=(tx)^3-t^3x+t^3x=(tx)^3=c^3$

for b we must have:

$a\cdot b+b=(tx)^3-t^3x+x^2-1=d^3$

Now let $(tx)^3-t^3x+x^2-1=(tx-1)^3$, then we have:

$(tx-1)^3=(tx)^3-3t^2x^2+3tx-1=(tx)^3+ x^2-t^3x-1$

Which gives:

$-3t^2x^2+3tx=x^2-t^3x$

$x[(t^3+3t)-(3t^2+1)x]=0$

$x=\frac{t^3+3t}{3t^2+1}$

This is parametric solution of x in terms of t. Hence this question can have infinite solutions.With $t=2$ ,I found $x=\frac{14}{13}$ which gives $a=\frac{112}{13}$ and $b=\frac{27}{169}$.

Comment: @user2661923, Sorry that was a bad typo. $\frac{112}{13}$ is correct. waiting for an answer. I will show my work.

Comment: Yes: `[20/7, 1/49], [25/2, 1/4], [27/5, 2/25], [81/44, 1/242], [98/27, 1/27], [112/13, 27/169], [175/81, 2/243], [208/135, 1/675], ...`.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov Computer search, or did you find a pattern?

Comment: @user2661923, computer search, based on "pattern" from example solution by @sirous as `denominator(a)=denominator(b)^2`

Comment: That's what I suspected.  But then, where did [98/27, 1/27], [175/81, 2/243], and [208/135, 1/675] come from?  Which scalar(s) were used re [denom-1, scalar $\times$ denom-1]? Also, where did [81/44, 1/242] come from?

Comment: `1/27=27/27^2`, `2/243=2*27/81^2`, `1/675=27/135^2`, `1/242=8/44^2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to sirous's method, we can get another parametric solution as follows.

From first equation, let $a=ct$ and $b=c^2/t-1$.
Substitute it to second equation, we obtain

$$c^3-ct+c^2/t-1 = d^3\tag{1}$$

Substitute $d=c-1$ to equation $(1)$, then we get $c = \frac{t(3+t)}{1+3t}$.

$$(a,b)=\left(\frac{t^2(3+t)}{1+3t}, \frac{(t-1)^3}{(1+3t)^2}\right)$$
$t$ is arbitrary.

If $t>1$ then $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Example:

```
              t        a            b         c         d
             [2][    20/7          1/49     10/7      3/7]
             [3][    27/5          2/25      9/5      4/5]
             [4][  112/13        27/169    28/13    15/13]
             [5][    25/2           1/4      5/2      3/2]
             [6][  324/19       125/361    54/19    35/19]
             [7][  245/11        54/121    35/11    24/11]
             [8][  704/25       343/625    88/25    63/25]
             [9][   243/7         32/49     27/7     20/7]
```

$$  $$
$$  $$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
ab+a = c^3 \\ 
ab+b = d^3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

We can get a parametric solution as follows (partial solution).

From first equation, let $a=c$ and $b=c^2-1$.
Substitute it to second equation, we obtain

$$c^3 + c^2 - c -1 = d^3\tag{1}$$
Since  equation $(1)$ has a solution $(c,d)=(1,0)$, then we can get a parametric solution below.

$$(a,b)=\left(\frac{-(k+1)(k^2-k+1)}{(k-1)(k^2+k+1)}, \frac{4k^3}{(k-1)^2(k^2+k+1)^2}\right)$$
$k$ is arbitrary.

If $0<k<1$ then $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Example:

```
               k         a           b         c         d
             [1/2][     9/7         32/49      9/7      8/7]
             [1/3][   14/13        27/169    14/13     9/13]
             [1/4][   65/63      256/3969    65/63    32/63]
             [1/5][   63/62      125/3844    63/62    25/62]
             [1/6][ 217/215     864/46225  217/215   72/215]
             [1/7][ 172/171     343/29241  172/171   49/171]
             [1/8][ 513/511   2048/261121  513/511  128/511]
             [1/9][ 365/364    729/132496  365/364   81/364]
             [2/3][   35/19       864/361    35/19    36/19]
             [2/5][ 133/117    4000/13689  133/117  100/117]
             [2/7][ 351/335  10976/112225  351/335  196/335]
             [2/9][ 737/721  23328/519841  737/721  324/721]
             [3/4][   91/37     6912/1369    91/37    96/37]
             [3/5][   76/49     3375/2401    76/49    75/49]
             [3/7][ 185/158    9261/24964  185/158  147/158]
             [3/8][ 539/485  55296/235225  539/485  384/485]
             [4/5][  189/61    32000/3721   189/61   200/61]
             [4/7][ 407/279   87808/77841  407/279  392/279]
             [4/9][ 793/665 186624/442225  793/665  648/665]
             [5/6][  341/91   108000/8281   341/91   360/91]
             [5/7][ 234/109   42875/11881  234/109  245/109]
             [5/8][ 637/387 256000/149769  637/387  640/387]
             [5/9][ 427/302   91125/91204  427/302  405/302]
             [6/7][ 559/127  296352/16129  559/127  588/127]
             [7/8][ 855/169  702464/28561  855/169  896/169]
             [7/9][ 536/193  250047/37249  536/193  567/193]
             [8/9][1241/217 1492992/47089 1241/217 1296/217]
```